# Result of map is NaN

Tags: angular, httpresponse, array.prototype.map

I have the following data structure in my mock services, and upon completion of the following chain as a result of map I receive NaN, however the values in my services are numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "person": [{
    "val1": 1,
    "val2": 2
  }],
  "facility": [{
    "val3": 3,
    "val4": 4
  }],
  "exposure": [{
    "val5": 5
  }]
}
```

The component where I am trying to get the result of the responses:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './entities/person';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  apiUrl1: string = 'http://localhost:3000/person/?';
  apiUrl2: string = 'http://localhost:3000/facility/?';
  apiUrl3: string = 'http://localhost:3000/exposure/?';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  createPerson(person: Person): Observable<any> {
    return (this.http.post(this.apiUrl1, person)
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1)))
  }

  getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return (this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg)
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1))
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + response.val2))
      .map((response: any) => response.val3 * response.val5)
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your responses don't match with what you want to map. Try logging the responses to see what they contain. I.e. if your last map response does not contain val3 and val5 then it returns NaN ofcourse.

Comment: I see. response.val3 is the response from the apiUrl2 and response.val5 is from apiUrl3. So how can I multiply them since val3 is not from the last api response?

Comment: if I log response it dislays: [{val5: 5}], hwowever if I log respnse.val5 it displays undefined

Comment: Thats because it is in an array (note the `[...]` brackets).

Comment: you need to use response[0].val1 for example